# Laravel math operations on SELECT statement

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7, yajra-datatable

I'm working on a query that has to retrive some columns from diferents tables and do the maths to calculate a product price based on the amount of needed material and the amount of work hours.

On one table I have the hour price (the price is set by the office location), on another table I have the material price (the materal price is set by material type of and the office location) and finally I have the products table where I set the total material and working hours needed.

The math I need to do is the following:

```
Total price = (price per hour * total needed hours) + (price per material * total needed hours)
```

This is the query I'm working on:

```
        // working hour price
        $mo = WorkForce::where('company_id', session()->get('currentCompany.id'))->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->get();

        // Material price
        $mt = MaterialPrice::where('company_id', session()->get('currentCompany.id'))->where('type_id', 4)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->get();

$query = $model->newQuery()
            ->leftJoin('materials', 'products.material_id', '=', 'materials.id')
            ->leftJoin('vehicles', 'products.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
            ->leftJoin('parts', 'products.part_id', '=', 'parts.id')
            ->select(
                'products.id as id',
                'products.name as product_name',
                'parts.part_name as part_name',
                'materials.public_name as material',
                'vehicles.name as vehicle',
                "(products.labour * $mo[0]) + (products.premium_modifier * $mt[0]) as price"
            )
            ->where('products.company_owner_id', session()->get('currentCompany.id'))
            ->orWhere('products.company_owner_id', null);
```

This query it's made to poblate a jquery datatable with `Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable`'s module. Now I see all the other columns fine but the column that should show the total price is empty and I don't see error messages. I'm not sure that Laravel allows this kind of maths on selects though.

In case it may be important we work with Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. For my case in particular on the DataTable class I work with I have a fuction defined that allows me to add columns 'on the fly' to add buttons and links generated from the table columns data.

Using this function I added a new column at the end of the table with the math operation's result.

Not sure if there's out a lot of projects with this same configuration though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass that part of the select as a `DB::raw` statement

```
DB::raw("(products.labour * $mo[0]) + (products.premium_modifier * $mt[0]) as price")
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result. Total price returns empty.

Comment: You may need to double-check the values. Try `Log::info("(products.labour * $mo[0]) + (products.premium_modifier * $mt[0])");` and see if the query looks correct, and also try selecting those particular columns to test the math yourself.

Comment: Normally if Laravel doesn't like a query, or it doesn't pass in correctly, it will throw an error instead of returning nothing.

Comment: The think is that with yajra datatables module I have to set a query (no execute it) and call a function that set the table columns on the view and possible that's where the issue is as Laravel is not complaing on the query.

Answer (score 0):

you must use `selectRaw` method for your desire:

```
$query = $model->newQuery()
            ->leftJoin('materials', 'products.material_id', '=', 'materials.id')
            ->leftJoin('vehicles', 'products.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
            ->leftJoin('parts', 'products.part_id', '=', 'parts.id')
            ->select(
                'products.id as id',
                'products.name as product_name',
                'parts.part_name as part_name',
                'materials.public_name as material',
                'vehicles.name as vehicle'
            )
            ->selectRaw("(products.labour * $mo[0]) + (products.premium_modifier * $mt[0]) as price")
            ->where('products.company_owner_id', session()->get('currentCompany.id'))
            ->orWhere('products.company_owner_id', null)
            ->get();
```